# Save the rows from a table's tbody in an array and use them later

Tags: javascript, arrays

It is a part of one of my projects and for this forum I made  a simple and short version of it. Here, I had a table first. I saved the rows from it's tbody in an array called `arr[]`. Then I deleted the tbody and created another one. Then I going to append the `tr` elements saved in `arr[]` to the newly created tbody.

```
tbody.appendChild(arr[i]);
```

But it isn't working as the way I want. No tr elements is appended to newly created tbody. How can I make this happen?

```js
    var table=document.createElement('table');
    var arr=[];
    table.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;');
    var thead=document.createElement('thead');
    thead.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;');
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        var row=thead.insertRow(i);
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
           var cell=row.insertCell(j);
            cell.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;text-align:center;');
           cell.innerHTML='tbheadCell'+j;
        }
        
    }
    table.appendChild(thead);
    var tbody=document.createElement('tbody');
    tbody.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;');
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        var row=tbody.insertRow(i);
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){
           var cell=row.insertCell(j);
            cell.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;text-align:center;');
           cell.innerHTML='tbodyCell'+j;
        } 
        arr.push(row);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    table.removeChild(tbody);
    var newtbody=document.createElement('tbody');
    tbody.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;');


    console.log(arr);
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){     
         tbody.appendChild(arr[i]);
    }
    table.appendChild(newtbody);
```

Comment: You're creating a new `tbody` as `newtbody`, but appending the rows to the old, removed  `tbody` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the last loop you are appneding arr to tbody and append newtbody.
you should write:

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){     
     newtbody.appendChild(arr[i]);
}
```